# error: package xxx does not exist . how do include packages in the build correctly?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use the project android-wheel from https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/
with Android Studio.

I imported them as modules and put the dependency for 'wheel' into the build.gradle of 'wheeldemo'.

when building it with gradle it shows errors, that packages do not exist, even though the imports in the java file don't show any errors:
[image]

I'm not sure, what I'm missing here. Might be something obvious, since I'm not to familiar with android programming, yet.

edit: here is the build.gradle of the wheeldemo module:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'kankan.wheel.demo'
        minSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':wheel')
}
```

Comment: could you add contents of your build.gradle here ?

Comment: I added the contents of the build.gradle for the wheeldemo. I guess that's the one that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the build.gradle of "wheel" has correct plugin type. It should be 'android-library' instead of 'com.android.application'.